# Jquery when back button is pressed

Tags: jquery, browser, back

I have a click that changes things on the page when you click it. I was wondering if there was a way to trigger an effect when you press the back button on the browser

Comment: Basically no but you could still have a look to onbeforeunload event which is not specific to browser's back button and which behaviour differs from browser to browser

Comment: You need to give more information and some sample of what u have done so far and any error u couldn't figure out . You question is very vague.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can sort of do it using the popstate event:

```
window.onpopstate = function() {
  alert("pop!");
}
```

or in **jQuery**:

```
$(window).on('popstate', function(event) {
 alert("pop");
});
```

However this will also trigger when navigating forward, not only backward.

Comment: Since it's tagged jQuery, you'd be better off suggesting `$(window).on("popstate", fn)`.

Comment: This is a very elegant solution.  Can it be extended just as elegantly to prevent a user navigating forwards or backwards?  (Note: This is in reference to an Ajax based site where the usual `onbeforeunload` approaches [don't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21583771/how-to-trigger-onbeforeunload-with-back-button-in-an-ajax-based-application)).

Comment: However, I don't know somehow it doesn't work after I go back and forth to the page a few times (using Chrome, Firefox)

Answer (score 14):

### Disable back url

```
$(function() {
    if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
        window.history.pushState('', null, './');
        $(window).on('popstate', function() {
            // alert('Back button was pressed.');
            document.location.href = '#';

        });
    }
});
```

Comment: that's a great hack. but gives a "Max Stack Size exceed" error on `document.location.href = '#';`

Comment: TL;DR: Thank you very much. Good move.

I agree that this is an extremely useful hack. Immediately pushing history state overcomes the unavailability of popstate when there is no current document history state. This enabled me to judiciously fire an event while a particular view is visible in my SPA that gives users (including me, who designed it) the propensity to use the back button rather than the in-page back button.

Answer (score 5):

use this code for detecting browser back button event

```
<script>
    if (performance.navigation.type == 2) {
        alert("Back button clicked");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: For me, this one detects the forward button, and nothing happens on the back button.

Comment: This detects Fwd/Back only AFTER you get to that page. Not the event BEFORE navigating

Answer (score 3):

You can simply fire the “popState” event in JQuery e.g:

```
$(window).on('popstate', function(event) {
    alert("pop");
});
```

This is enough for what you asked … but here are few add on window event to go with…

```
$(window).on('pushstate', function(event) {
    alert("push");
}); // This one pushes u to forward page through history...

window.history.replaceState(); //work exactly like pushstate bt this one replace the history instead of creating new one...
window.history.backward(); // To move backward through history, just fire this event...
window.history.forward();// To move forward through history ...
window.history.go(-1); // Go back to one page(or whatever value u passed) through history
window.history.go(1); // Go forward to one page through history..
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `popstate` to detect when back.

```js
$(window).on('popstate', function(event) {
  alert("You are going to back page. Can work that?");
});
```

```css
button {
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: limegreen;
  border: 1px limegreen solid;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="window.history.back()">Back</button>
    <p>Or you can click on browser back button.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you if work.!.?