# How to stay fancy box popup sometime after click on the browser back button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, browser

I want to show a popup when user click on the close button or back button in browser in checkout page of my site. I have implemented the following code for that ........

```
function PopIt() { 
    $("a#trigger").trigger('click');
    window.onbeforeunload = UnPopIt;
    return "Would you like to join our mailing list for other offers?"; 
}
function UnPopIt()  { /* nothing to return */ } 

$(document).ready(function() {
    //window.history.forward();
    window.onbeforeunload = PopIt;

    $("a#trigger").fancybox({
            'hideOnContentClick': false,
            'hideOnOverlayClick': false,
            'showCloseButton': true
    });

    $("a[id!=trigger]").click(function(){ window.onbeforeunload = UnPopIt; });

});
```

Now everything is working fine. But the final requirement is when user click on the back browser button from the checkout page, the fancy box popup appear and it will stay ~40 seconds then the page redirect to back.

I can't solve this problem. How do I stay the popup when already the page redirecting to click on the back button on browser. Is it possible? Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried (@user1721135) 
[Jquery when back button is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17628612/jquery-when-back-button-is-pressed)

I understand is a different event but maybe can help :S.... Also: (@IMRAN ABDUL GHANI) [Solution to browser back button click event handling](http://www.webdevelopmenthelp.net/2013/12/browser-back-button-click-event.html)